# .Each em dois elementos com valores em variáveis diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho dois elementos, horaFim e horaInicio que são dois inputs e ambos possuem a classe hora.

Com o each preciso ter o value dos dois separados em variaveis.

```
$('.hora').each(function (){
  var horaFinal = $('.horaFinal').val();
  var horaInicio = $('.horaInicio').val();
})
```

Porém quando faço isso meus inputs estão vazios.

Comment: Podes explicar em que contexto estás a usar esse código? coloca o que está à volta para percebermos melhor o contexto.

Comment: Qual é o propósito? são apenas dois inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Se você sabe que são apenas dois inputs um pra inicial e outro pra final você não precisa percorrer com `each`

Basta pegar o primeiro e o ultimo elemento com a classe `hora`:

```
var horaInicial = $('.hora').first().val();
var horaFinal = $('.hora').last().val();
```